# How can i do this DELETE Query with subselect or LEFT join

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to delete task FROM my task table WHERE the task id is for example 100 and the task WHERE created by the deleting user or a MEMBER of his team who have a smaller user_role assigned to them in the user table

I am wondering if something like this will do the magic or what is the correct way to achieve this?

```
DELETE FROM tasks t LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = 1 WHERE task_id = 677 
AND createdby 
IN((SELECT u1.user_id FROM users u1 WHERE u1.user_team = u.user_team 
AND taskrspnsble 
IN((SELECT u2.user_id FROM users u2 WHERE u2.user_role <= u.user_role))
))
```

Comment: A LEFT JOIN on a DELETE is an incredibly rare thing? I wonder why.

Comment: I just looking for an easy way delete one task from my db whit only using two external factors (task_id, user) but still apply some requirements. Thats all ;-) Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you want the logic to do.  There is probably an easier way to express it.  However, `delete t from . . .` might fix your problem.

Comment: you are right, doesn't work... back to my question? whats the logic to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I think my logic explained is pretty clear? I just figured out to. Here the correct answer!

```
 DELETE FROM tasks 

WHERE task_id = 1 
AND createdby IN(
                (SELECT u1.user_id FROM users u1 WHERE u1.user_team 
                 IN
                 (SELECT u2.user_team FROM users u2 WHERE u2.user_role <= (SELECT u3.user_id FROM users u3 WHERE u3.user_id = 1)
                )
                ))
```

Comment: I doubt that this does whatever you think it does.